# NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for Sun, 19 Jan 2014:Date

Tags: ruby, date, iterator, date-range, nomethoderror

I'm trying to iterate over a `Date` range.

`date_value_start` and `date_value_end` are two values of the `Date` class.

Why is the code below returning the error message: "NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for Sun, 19 Jan 2014:Date"

```
date_value_start..date_value_end.each {|i| puts i}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `.each` on the date object. You should call it on the `range`

Try

```
(date_value_start..date_value_end).each {|i| puts i}
```